# Remove pattern from URL and 301 redirect to the new URL

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, redirect, routes, url-rewriting

Suppose the following:

```
mywebsite.com/searches/index/page:x  where x is an integer.
```

I want to remove index/ and redirect to

```
mywebsite.com/searches/page:x
```

My web application is based on CakePHP, and I added the following line to the .htaccess file in webroot directory, but it does not get any result.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/searches/index/(.*)$ searches/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**I need to know the correct .htaccess code should I use.**

However, I asked this question because google webmasters tools told me that there are many soft 401 errors. In my app routes I omitted calling the index page by the following lines in routes.php:

```
 Router::connect('/searches/index/*', array('controller' => 'error','action'=>'e404'));
Router::connect('/searches', array('controller' => 'searches', 'action' => 'index','page' => 1)); 
Router::connect('/searches/*', array('controller' => 'searches', 'action' => 'index'));
```

So if there is another solution to overcome the Google issue from the CakePHP, I will be appreciated to know it.

My cake version is 1.2.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group at the beginning of your rule will cause the rule to match URIs like `mywebsite.com/searches/index/page:x` as well as URIs like `mywebsite.com/foobar/searches/index/page:x`. It doesn't look like this is what you want.

Also you are utilizing the [backreference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond) for the first group in your replacement pattern, which causes the new URL to never contain the `page:x` part. Instead it would redirect to `mywebsite.com/searches` for a URI like `mywebsite.com/searches/index/page:x`, and to `mywebsite.com/searches/foobar` for a URI like `mywebsite.com/foobar/searches/index/page:x`.

I think your rule should more look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?searches/index/(.*)$ /searches/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note that apart from removing the first group, I've also made the leading slash in the pattern optional since it's [forbidden with Apache 2.x, while it's necessary with Apache 1.x](http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/), and I've added a leading slash in the replacement part in order to make sure it will redirect to the root.

Comment: Is there a reason why this was down-voted? It would be nice to know what's wrong with the answer so that I could correct possible mistakes, ambiguities or the like.